# Perform validation based on the visibility of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have a Form which has 2 fields to validate, Radio buttons and Textarea.

The rules for validation are

- At least 1 radio must be checked
- The textarea should not be empty.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w26xk/) of my code.

The issue is that the visibility of "Radio" buttons are conditional and they might be hidden in some scenario.

So. currently if the Radio buttons are hidden I'm not able to submit the `<form>`.

Should I do the Form validation twice as shown below? Or is there a better and shorter way of doing this validation?

```
if (Radio is : visible){ 
  Here goes the validation for both form fields
} else{
  Do the Validation again only for Textarea
}
```

Following is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <input class="redButton" id="openDialogButton" type="button" value="Open Dialog">
    <div id="sessionReason" title="End Transaction">
        <p class="validation-summary-errors marginBottom10">Provide the following information to proceed:</p>
        <div class="marginBottom" id="sessionDocumentMessage">
            <label class="marginBottom5 marginTop10">Return the document?</label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sessionDocuments" />Return</label>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sessionDocuments" />Keep</label>
            <br>
        </div>
        <p class="marginBottom5" id="sessionReasonMessage">Reason for ending the transaction:</p>
        <textarea id="sessionReasonBox" class="reasonBox"></textarea>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
    function showValidationError() {
        $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').show();
    }

    function hideValidationError() {
        $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').hide();
    }

    function addRadioError() {
        $("#sessionDocumentMessage label").addClass("redtext");
    }

    function removeRadioError() {
        $("#sessionDocumentMessage label").removeClass("redtext");
    }

    function addReasonBoxError() {
        $("#sessionReasonMessage").addClass("redtext");

    }

    function removeReasonBoxError() {
        $("#sessionReasonMessage").removeClass("redtext");
    }

    $('#sessionReason .validation-summary-errors').hide();
    $("#sessionReason").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function () {
                var enteredReason = $('#sessionReasonBox').val();
                var radioChecked = $("#sessionReason input:radio[name='sessionDocuments']:checked");

                if ((enteredReason.length <= 0) && (radioChecked.length == 0)) {
                    //Show Error
                    showValidationError();
                    addReasonBoxError();
                    addRadioError();
                    //Hide Validation Error
                } else if ((enteredReason.length > 0) && (radioChecked.length == 0)) {
                    //Show Validation Error
                    showValidationError();
                    addRadioError();
                    //Hide Validation Error
                    removeReasonBoxError();
                } else if ((enteredReason.length <= 0) && (radioChecked.length > 0)) {
                    //Show Validation Error
                    showValidationError();
                    addReasonBoxError();
                    //Hide Validation Error
                    removeRadioError();
                } else {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    //Hide Validation Error
                    hideValidationError();
                    removeRadioError();
                    removeReasonBoxError();
                }
            },
                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });



    $("#openDialogButton").click(function () {
        $('#sessionReasonBox').val("");
        $('#sessionDocumentMessage input:radio').removeAttr('checked');
        $("#sessionReason").dialog("open");
        //Hide Validation Error
        hideValidationError();
        removeRadioError();
        removeReasonBoxError();
    });
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: How about checking the visibility in a single function..? :/

Comment: check the answer… might give you an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following, this should give you an idea.

```
"Submit": function () {
   var enteredReason = $('#sessionReasonBox').val();
   var radioVisible = $("#sessionReason input:radio[name='sessionDocuments']:visible");
   var radioChecked = $("#sessionReason input:radio[name='sessionDocuments']:checked");
   var validationError = false;
   if(enteredReason.length <= 0) {
     validationError = true; // validation failure
     addReasonBoxError(); //add validation error for textarea
   }
   else
     removeReasonBoxError(); //remove validation error for textarea
   if(radioVisible.length){
     if (radioChecked.length == 0) {
        validationError = true; // validation failure
        addRadioError(); //add validation error for radio
     }
      else 
         removeRadioError(); //remove validation error for radio
   }
   if(validationError)
      showValidationError(); //add validation error
   else
      hideValidationError() //remove validation error
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the css-property.

```
if (!($('button').css('display') === "hidden"))
```

The css-function, if given a single argument, just returns the value rather than setting it. Also, you would of course have to refine the selector to select the correct button.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/css/